# Transition for js height change

Tags: javascript, transition

Hey guys I hope you can help me with my following problem.

Here is the relevant fragment of the js-code :

var layone = document.getElementById('lone');
...

```
    if(layone && layone.style) {
    layone.style.height = 'auto';
    layone.style.width = '120%';
    layone.style.marginLeft = '-40px';
    }
```

...

Now I want to give it a smooth transition. Any help ?

Thank you very much so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this function to do some fade in kind of transition...

```
function do_transition(){
    $('#lone').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#lone').html('New content in MyDiv ('+Math.random()+')')
        setTimeout(function() { $('#lone').fadeIn('slow'); }, 5000);
    });    
}
```

if you want to move your "lone" just change margin values of "lone" from JS...

```
<head>
<title>JavaScript Animation</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var imgObj = null;
var animate ;
function init(){
   imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
   imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
   imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
}
function moveRight(){
   imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
   animate = setTimeout(moveRight,20); // call moveRight in 20msec
}
function stop(){
   clearTimeout(animate);
   imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
}
window.onload =init;
</head>
<body>
<form>
<div id="myImage"> </div>
<p>Click the buttons below to handle animation</p>
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="moveRight();" />
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stop();" />
</form>
</body>
```

try this for moving div around

for scroll down image changes  follow this example

http://jsfiddle.net/WTkqn/

put your different image in img src... and then some fade in animations if you want

Comment: Well, I am pretty new to the world around html. can you show me how I may implement this. The "lone" object is an image in my html and is visible from the start. Could you do an example ? thank you so far

Comment: Just clear me a thing.. do you want to fade out your image or move arround your page.. ? transition mean what ? i ll surely help you

Comment: I got like 5 images stacked and want to stretch one . It should look like you scroll into the page (the page is dennis-osswald.de there you can see what i am talking about)

Comment: As is said . in the end I want to have a scroll-in page. You got the different forest layers in the front and the mountain-layer in the back. If you scroll once you should zoom nearer to layer one (there I want to place the first point of the menue) . For the next scroll I want everything come closer and the first layer should disappear. and so on. I hope you understand :)

Comment: try that demo @DennisOßwald and make some animation changes as you want... like zoom in or fade out or what ever... just google some css tricks for that

Comment: Thank you Prabhu Vignesh Rajagopal . Will play a bit with it . Think it will do what i need :)